# Check value of textfield

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How can I check the value of a textfield ? I just want to clear the field if current text matches a certain val -

```
$('#username').click(function() {
    if($("#username").getVal() == "Username"){
        $("#username").val("");
        return false;      
    }
});
```

`if($("#username").getVal() == "Username"){` is pseudocode for what im trying to acheive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you provide no argument to [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val), it returns the current value. If you provide a string, it sets the value to that string.  So you're not far off...

```
$('#username').click(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "Username"){
        $(this).val('');
        return false;      
    }
});
```

Note also that I have changed your code slightly further.  You had several identical selections `$('#username')`.  Within an event handler, you can use the `this` keyword to refer to the element that was clicked.  You can then wrap this in the [jQuery constructor](http://api.jquery.com/jquery) to run the jQuery functions.

However, you can go one better by checking the `value` property of the element itself:

```
$('#username').click(function() {
    if(this.value == "Username"){
        this.value = '';
        return false;      
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for adding the option to eliminate unnecessary function calls.

Answer (score 0):

It's called [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
if ($('#username').val() === "Username") {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#username').click(function() {
   if($(this).val() == "Username"){
          $(this).val("");
          return false;      
   }
});
```